# How to disable stepping in C++ template while walking thru code using GDB?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am trying to walk thru code using GDB, and GDB always tries to show C++ templates source code which makes debugging inconvenient and wastes lots of my time.

GDB tries to step in the function and it shows an error when it can't find files where templates are implemented, or it jumps into template code which I don't want to see.

I couldn't find a method of how to disable showing/stepping into container or template source code. I want to just step over, but I don't know if that feature is available.

Is it possible to disable step into template while debugging with GDB? When I step over for ex. `make_unique` function, I expect GDB to not trying to show `make_unique` implementation. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `next`, instead of `step`? Or if you accidentally entered into a function which you don't want to debug, use `finish`.

Answer (score 4):

One can use `next` command to step over a function call, or `finish` to step out of a function.

Another way is to use `skip` or `skip file` command. This makes GDB always skip unwanted functions or source files, even when using the `step` command.

This is not always what one wants however. For example, when debugging a comparison function used in `std::sort`, one wants to step directly into the comparison function, skipping all of the `std::sort` implementation. Or one want to step into a constructor, skipping the `std::make_unique` implementation.

Unfortunately this is not possible with GDB (without setting a breakpoint). When skipping a function or a file, GDB also skips everything called *from* that function or file.

Another prominent debugger has the desired functionality, known as [Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019), but it is only available for Windows.

For some reason, the "skip file" feature of GDB is sometimes touted as equivalent to "Just My Code". It is not.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I don't know how to tell VSCode to use `next` command instead of `step`. if it really uses `step` GDB command when `step over` button is clicked, this should resolve my problem.

Comment: @sam Look at the debugger buttons, the icons are self explanatory

Comment: There's a feature request for this: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23540. But it's unlikely to be implemented as JMC as done by msvc requires the compiler instrumenting the code.

Answer (score 3):

`skip` is what you want. You can skip functions or files.

If you step into some unwanted code you can use `skip this` to skip the function you just step into or `skip file` to skip the file where it is.

At any moment you can also use `skip function_name` or `skip filename` and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> after a few characters will make gdb complete the name for you.

It is also possible so specify function names or file names using a regular expressions or a glob file pattern, respectively.

For common things you always want to skip you should add the skip commands to the `.gdbinit` file in your home folder. For instance, I have the code below in my `.gdbinit`.

```
# Skip the Catch library functions  when stepping into
skip -rfu Catch
skip -rfu _catch_sr

# Skip everything from the std namespace
skip -rfu ^std::
skip -rfu ^gsl::
# Skip everything in SFML workspace
skip -rfu ^sf::
skip -rfu ^arma::
skip -rfu ^Glue
```

With regular expressions, it means gdb will skip anything in the `std` namespace as well from a few other libraries I use regularly, such as [catch](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), etc.

For the glob pattern you could do something such as

```
skip -gfile /usr/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/*
```

Unfortunately, the glob pattern does not seem to handle something such as "any file in any subfolder of some folder". It would be very useful if gdb allowed something such as

```
skip -gfile /home/myuser/.conan/**/*
```

to skip any file in a subfolder from the `.conan` folder, for instance. This folder is where the [conan](https://conan.io/) package manager installs the libraries. Then with a single `skip` command gdb would not step into any external library code.

Comment: About `-gfile **`: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22198