# When debugging C++ code using Visual Studio Code, is it possible to automatically step over standard includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

Environment: Using Visual Studio Code with the Standard Microsoft C++ Debugging Extension. Using gdb as the underlying debugger.

For example: on the code below a step in on the commented line will jump to the standard string header.

Is there a way to avoid this?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "Example String"; /// < Step IN here 

    std::cout << a << std::endl; 
}
```

A more realistic example of why this is a problem:
In the case below I want to debug the a->methodToDebug()
but step in will send you to the source for the std::unique_ptr get method. You can still keep stepping in to get to your own code, but in more complicated code it becomes a pain.

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public: 
    int methodToDebug() { 
        return -1 ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>();

    auto s = a->methodToDebug(); // <<-- Step in here, goes to get().
}
```

Comment: You want step in to do a step over instead? Why not step over explicitly?

Comment: [Debug only user code with Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022)

Comment: For a simple case you can step over - a better example would be code that uses smart pointers to access a class - I want to step into the method, not the smart pointer code.

Comment: VSCode is an editor without debugger. You have to describe how you use VSCode to debug your code.

Comment: Updated the question - but it is using the standard C++ Extension from Microsoft

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable justMyCode in VS Code C++ debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894675/how-to-enable-justmycode-in-vs-code-c-debugger)

Answer (score 2):

It appears I can do this for recent versions of gdb(7.12.1 or higher) with the following in the .gdbinit file

```
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*/*
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/58159664/775806

Answer (score 1):

Turn on: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > [ ] **Enable Just My Code**.

Comment: Visual Studio Code - not Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio is in the title of your question. Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio are very different tools.

Comment: Sorry - The tag was correct - I have edited the title