Is it possible to use .natstepfilter files in Visual Studio Code to avoid stepping into chosen C++ functions
The Just My Code feature does not work in Visual Studio Code for C++. Is it possible to get the older, regex-based .natstepfilter file approach to work instead?
Unlike Visualizers, which I can enable by simply adding  "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/my_visualizer.natvis" to my .vscode/launch.json, there is no obvious way to point to a .natstepfilter file. I have tried editing both

the global C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter; and
the local, Visual Studio Code specific C:\Users%USERNAME%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.20.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\vsdbg\bin\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter.

However neither approach seems to make any difference, although it's possible I've made a silly mistake. Has anyone got this to work, if so, how?

Non-answer: No :-( But RemedyBG is great, supports .natjmc/.natstepfilter, and apparently has a vs code integration...

JustMyCode functionality cannot work on filename patterns alone. It requires compiler cooperation. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58159664/775806

@n.m.couldbeanAI Per the linked github issue, in particular this comment, JustMyCode doesn't work for the forseeable. I'm interested in the older regex-based "Don't step into this function" functionality, which in the bad old days was accessible via a registry key, and now is accessible via file(s).
